# Does a submanifold of nonzero codimension have measure zero under the product of non atomic measures?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, geometric-measure-theory

Let $A$ be a non atomic measure on $\mathbb R$. Consider the product measure $\mu := A \times \dots \times A$ on $\mathbb R^n$.

**Question:** Let $M$ be a $n-1$ dimensional smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$. Is it true that $M$ has measure $0$ under $\mu$?

Comment: If there's a projection $p_i$ whose fibers are countable, you can use Cavalieri's principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A   submanifold $M$ of ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ (with codimension 1) can always (after permuting the coordinates) be locally represented in the form $G_f=\{(x,y) : y=f(x)\}$ where $x$ runs over $V \subset {\mathbb R}^{n-1}$ and $f:V \to {\mathbb R}$. That implies that $M$ is contained in a  countable union of such graphs. Each graph has measure zero under the given product measure by Fubini since $A$ is nonatomic. Thus  $M$ indeed has measure zero under the product measure by countable additivity.

A   submanifold $M$ of ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ with positive codimension is always a subset of a manifold of codimension 1.

Comment: Hm, the comment on the graph having measure $0$ by Fubini - this implicitly assumes that the induced measure after permuting the coordinates is still a product of nonatomic measures right? How does one see this?

Comment: @Nate River: You just permute the coordinates, relative to which it is a product of measures. So you really only permute these non-atomic measures.

Comment: Permuting the coordinates preserves the product measure $A \times\ldots \times A$. And this is just a notational device so the map $f$ takes the first $n-1$ coordinates to the last one.

Comment: Oh, its literally only a permutation of coordinates, instead of a more general transformation. That makes sense, thanks! I actually did not know you could always write it this way as a graph with only a permutation of coordinates. 
@Yuval Peres